# How to mock Function interface from java 8 and System class

Tags: java, mockito, junit4, junit5, powermock

I want to mock below call :

```
((Function<String, String>) System::getenv).apply(TransformerConstants.TRANSFORMER_POOL_SIZE)
```

I tried using below code :

```
PowerMockito.when(((Function<String, String>) System::getenv).apply(TransformerConstants.PRECISE_ID_TRANSFORMER_POOL_SIZE)).thenReturn("dsad");
```

But its giving below error :

**org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
For example:
when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);**

Let me know how this entire call can be mocked.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to *mock* `System::getenv`. Instead, structure your code so that you can replace that method reference with some other value (a mock or just an inline test lambda):

```
objectToTest.setGetEnvFunction(key -> testValue);
```

Comment: Earlier it was  val poolSize = System.getenv(TRANSFORMER_POOL_SIZE); but due to Sonarqube issue I have to change that to ((Function<String, String>) System::getenv).apply(TransformerConstants.TRANSFORMER_POOL_SIZE)  so I don't think so it can be restructured as Sonarqube will report critical issue again ..

Comment: @PracheerPancholi I suspect that all you're doing with your change is confusing Sonarqube so that it forgot about the underlying problem that's still there. Most likely you need to actually _fix_ whatever it was warning about (potentially missing return value?).

Comment: do you have any suggestions how this can be changed so that neither there will be any sonarqube issue not there will be any code coverage issue and that piece of code can be unit tested ..

Comment: @PracheerPancholi Start by not saying "issue" and instead showing _the actual exact error_.

Comment: Sorry didnt get you what you are trying to say @chrylis can you please elaborate on this and how to address this issue ?

Comment: Can you propose some code which I can try to address this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do so this with :

```
 @Test
 @SetEnvironmentVariable(key = TransformerConstants.TRANSFORMER_POOL_SIZE, value = "sadsa")
 public void testCreateMapper_invalidTransformerPoolSize(){
     Assert.assertTrue(factory.createMapper(null) instanceof StandardMapper);
 }
```